# Поменять текст в Spinner при вводе текста из EditText

Tags: android, android-spinner

В parent layout у меня есть Spinner и EditText. Нужно сделать так, чтобы при вводе в EditText текста у спиннера одновременно изменялся текст на вводимый. Что и где нужно прописать для реализации такой фичи?

Comment: спинер - компонент для выбора фиксированных значений из списка, какой еще текст должен заменяться на вводимый? в чем вообще смысл такого нелепого юзкейса?

Comment: Это нужно, чтобы пользователь видел изменения текста.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Settings_Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnKeyListener{
//.............
static EditText edUserId;
edUserId = this.findViewById(R.id.mUserId);
edUserId.setOnKeyListener(this);
//...............

@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.edUserId:
            Spinner.setText ....
и т.д.
```